# linq ordered subset of another list

Tags: c#, linq, set

There are lots and lots of questions on SO about finding if one list is the subset of another list.

i.e. `bool isSubset = !t2.Except(t1).Any();`

I can't seem to find one that accounts for order

as in given a sequence:

`1,1,2,5,8,1,9,1,2`

The subsequences...

`2,5,8,1,9` true

`1,2,5,8,1` true

`5,2,1` false

`1,2,5,1,8` false

`1,1,2` true

`1,1,1,2` false

Comment: That's essentially pattern matching, like in `string.Contains(string)`.

Comment: i used numbers to simplify my issue (which involves objects). I suppose my problem's context clouded that obvious fact

Comment: It's also more obvious if you've ever generalised string out to elements other than characters before or not. After the first time one comes across that, other cases that are generalisations of strings stand out. Anyway, as such I'd say go with Knuth–Morris–Pratt as per my answer unless you've a good reason to use another (such as Aho–Corasick for finding a set of sub-lists simultaneously)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A list in which the order is significant is a generalisation of the concept of *string*. Therefore you want to use a substring-finding algorithm.

There are several possibilities, but Knuth–Morris–Pratt is a good choice. It has some initial Θ(m) overhead where m is the length of the sublist sought, and then finds in Θ(n) where n is the distance to the sublist sought, or the length of the whole list if it isn't there. This beats the simple item-by-item compare which is Θ((n-m+1) m):

```
public static class ListSearching
{
  public static bool Contains<T>(this IList<T> haystack, IList<T> needle)
  {
    return Contains(haystack, needle, null);
  }
  public static bool Contains<T>(this IList<T> haystack, IList<T> needle, IEqualityComparer<T> cmp)
  {
    return haystack.IndexOf(needle, cmp) != -1;
  }
  public static int IndexOf<T>(this IList<T> haystack, IList<T> needle)
  {
    return IndexOf(haystack, needle, null);
  }
  public static int IndexOf<T>(this IList<T> haystack, IList<T> needle, IEqualityComparer<T> cmp)
  {
    if(haystack == null || needle == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException();
    int needleCount = needle.Count;
    if(needleCount == 0)
      return 0;//empty lists are everywhere!
    if(cmp == null)
      cmp = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    int count = haystack.Count;
    if(needleCount == 1)//can't beat just spinning through for it
    {
      T item = needle[0];
      for(int idx = 0; idx != count; ++idx)
        if(cmp.Equals(haystack[idx], item))
          return idx;
      return -1;
    }
    int m = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int[] table = KMPTable(needle, cmp);
    while(m + i < count)
    {
      if(cmp.Equals(needle[i], haystack[m + i]))
      {
        if(i == needleCount - 1)
          return m == needleCount ? -1 : m;//match -1 = failure to find conventional in .NET
        ++i;
      }
      else
      {
        m = m + i - table[i];
        i = table[i] > -1 ? table[i] : 0;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }
  private static int[] KMPTable<T>(IList<T> sought, IEqualityComparer<T> cmp)
  {
    int[] table = new int[sought.Count];
    int pos = 2;
    int cnd = 0;
    table[0] = -1;
    table[1] = 0;
    while(pos < table.Length)
      if(cmp.Equals(sought[pos - 1], sought[cnd]))
        table[pos++] = ++cnd;
      else if(cnd > 0)
        cnd = table[cnd];
      else
        table[pos++] = 0;
    return table;
  }
}
```

Testing this:

```
var list = new[]{ 1, 1, 2, 5, 8, 1, 9, 1, 2 };
Console.WriteLine(list.Contains(new[]{2,5,8,1,9})); // True
Console.WriteLine(list.Contains(new[]{1,2,5,8,1})); // True
Console.WriteLine(list.Contains(new[]{5,2,1}));     // False
Console.WriteLine(list.Contains(new[]{1,2,5,1,8})); // False
Console.WriteLine(list.Contains(new[]{1,1,2}));     // True
Console.WriteLine(list.Contains(new[]{1,1,1,2}));   // False
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no such function in .net. You need Knuth–Morris–Pratt algo for it. One guy already implemented it as linq extension https://code.google.com/p/linq-extensions/

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
var source = new [] { 1,1,2,5,8,1,9,1,2 };

Func<int[], int[], bool> contains =
    (xs, ys) =>
        Enumerable
            .Range(0, xs.Length)
            .Where(n => xs.Skip(n).Take(ys.Length).SequenceEqual(ys))
            .Any();

Console.WriteLine(contains(source, new [] { 2,5,8,1,9 })); // true
Console.WriteLine(contains(source, new [] { 1,2,5,8,1 })); // true
Console.WriteLine(contains(source, new [] { 5,2,1 })); // false
Console.WriteLine(contains(source, new [] { 1,2,5,1,8 })); // false
Console.WriteLine(contains(source, new [] { 1,1,2 })); // true
Console.WriteLine(contains(source, new [] { 1,1,1,2 })); // false
```

Comment: O((n-m+1) m) for a substring search though.

Comment: If you're searching through for `1, 1, 3, 4` and you've found `1, 1, 2` you shouldn't jump forward one step, because you've seen enough to know that that won't match either. The next possible match has to be after the `1, 1, 2` you've just examined, so you should move forward 3 steps.

Comment: @JonHanna - I couldn't agree more. However there's always a trade off. I have opted for code readability rather than efficiency. An efficient solution is more difficult to reason about. I think it is better to first go for readability and then optimize when you have a performance problem.

Comment: True, but it's easier still not to reason about it at all and just go with old dependable approaches.

Answer (score 0):

there is a workaround to the limitation. You can change the enumerable to a string and then make use of the `Contains` method.

```
 var t1 = new List<int> {1, 1, 2, 5, 8, 1, 9, 1, 2};
         var t2 = new List<int> {2,5,8,1,9};
         var t3 = new List<int> {5,2,1};

         var t1Str = String.Join(",", t1);

t1Str.Contains(String.Join(",", t2););//true
t1Str.Contains(String.Join(",", t3););//false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own extension, I wrote a simple IsSubset method:

**Console App for testing:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<int> { 1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6 };
        var subList = new List<int> { 3, 5};
        var subList2 = new List<int> { 1, 4 };

        bool isSublist1 = subList.IsSubset(list);

        bool isSublist2 = subList2.IsSubset(list);

        Console.WriteLine(isSublist1 + "; " + isSublist2);
        /* True; False */

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
```

**IEnumerable Extension:**

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static bool IsSubset<T>(this IEnumerable<T> subsetEnumerable, IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        var found = false;

        var list = enumerable as IList<T> ?? enumerable.ToList();
        var listCount = list.Count();

        var subsetList = subsetEnumerable as IList<T> ?? subsetEnumerable.ToList();
        var posListCount = subsetList.Count();

        /* If the SubList is bigger, it can't be a sublist */
        if (listCount < posListCount) { 
            return false;
        }

        /* find all indexes of the first item of the sublist in the list */
        var firstElement = subsetList.First();
        var indexes = new List<int>();
        var index = 0;
        foreach (var elem in list)
        {
            if (elem.Equals(firstElement))
            {
                indexes.Add(index);
            }
            index++;
        }

        /* check all first item founds for the subsequence */
        foreach (var i in indexes)
        {
            int x=0;
            for (x = 0; x < posListCount && (i + x) < listCount; x++)
            {
                if (!Equals(subsetList[x], list[(i + x)]))
                {
                    found = false;
                    break;
                }
                found = true;
            }

            if (x + 1 < posListCount)
                found = false;
        }

        return found;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be using join can get you what you want. Join will return the matching records. If record count is greater than 0 than there is a match else no match.

Below I have explained through a sample code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee> 
        {
            new Employee{EmpID = 1},
            new Employee{EmpID = 1},
            new Employee{EmpID = 2},
            new Employee{EmpID = 5},
            new Employee{EmpID = 8},
            new Employee{EmpID = 1},
            new Employee{EmpID = 9},
            new Employee{EmpID = 1},
            new Employee{EmpID = 2}
        };

        List<Manager> mgrList = new List<Manager> 
        {
            new Manager{ManagerID = 7},
            new Manager{ManagerID = 3},
            new Manager{ManagerID = 6}               
        };

        var result = (from emp in empList
                     join mgr in mgrList on emp.EmpID equals mgr.ManagerID
                     select new { emp.EmpID}).Count();

        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Employee
{ 
    public int EmpID { get; set; } 
}

public class Manager
{ 
    public int ManagerID { get; set; }
}
```